# "Не идёт ли сейчас эпидемия..." - эпидемия ходит?

Tags: выбор-слов

Не могу подобрать нужной глагол...

> Важно узнать, не идёт ли сейчас где-то эпидемия какой-нибудь
>   экзотической болезни, благоприятна ли погода.

Comment: Возникла, наблюдается, развивается эпидемия

Comment: М_Г, давай ответом - ЛОшечку вручу! )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возникла, началась, наблюдается, объявлена, развивается эпидемия

Comment: Ок! Наблюдается.

Answer (score 2):

Важно узнать, НЕТ ли сейчас где-то эпидемиИ какой-нибудь экзотической болезни, благоприятна ли погода.